# How to create text paragraph for results in R?

Tags: r, text, copy-paste, analysis

I'm writing my results (both text and tables) and the process is quite time-consuming...
I was wondering if a function in R could help me paste my results into the text so I could copy it into WORD?

For example:
R square = *put number here*, B = *put number here*... The difference between the models was significant/nonsignificant with p < *put number here*

Then I would love to paste it into WORD.

Best regards,

Daniel

Couldn't find any function that would help me... Tried Flextable...

Comment: Hello Daniel, please pasete a reproducibe example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, this can largely be done in base R and reported with R Markdown or Quarto. You can either write the document as a `.qmd` or `.rmd` file and export to word, or simply render in RStudio and then copy and paste as you like.

I work the following way:

- First assign the models to variables using `<-`.
- Then examine the structure of the model with `str()`.
- In the text of the document, use `$` with the variable name to access the various parts. Or paste it in the console for cut and paste of the values.

You may want to `round()` some numbers. Additionally, the function `scales::pvalue()` is very helpful for p values.

```r
library(scales)
```

```r
# Generate some model and assign it to a variable
model <- cor.test(cars$speed, cars$dist)
```

```r
# Examine the structure of the model object
str(model)
```

[image]

Then in the text of an R markdown or Quarto document you can write:

> $r$(`r model$parameter`) = `r round(model$estimate, digits = 2)`, $p$= `r pvalue(model$p.value, accuracy = 0.05)`

This will give the following: ***r*(48) = 0.81, *p*= <0.05**

In a code chunk `$` is used to access a component. In text `$` is used to start an equation. That can be confusing. To access a piece of R code in R Markdown text, use the convention `r <function or variable>` as in `r model$parameter` above. Alternatively, you can simply paste `model$parameter` into the console and copy the results to your target document.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could knit the document to word, here's a quick example using inline R:

````
---
title: "test.Rmd"
output: word_document
---

``` {r, echo = FALSE}
# some variables
a <- 24
b <- 100
```

R square = `r a`, B = `r b` ... The difference between the models was `r if (a == 24) {"significant"} else {"insignificant"}` with p < `r b - a`
````